# .Net SimpleJson: Deserialize JSON to dynamic object

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm using the SimpleJson library from here: http://simplejson.codeplex.com/

I'd like to deserialize a JSON string to an dynamic object like this:

```
dynamic json = SimpleJson.SimpleJson.DeserializeObject("{\"foo\":\"bar\"}");

var test = json.foo;
```

The deserialization part works properly, but calling json.foo throws a RuntimeBinderException with the error message `'SimpleJson.JsonObject' does not contain a definition for 'foo'`.

How can I deserialize a JSON string using SimpleJson and access the dynamic properties using the json.foo syntax?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, it's just a matter of reading the source code for SimpleJson. :-)  A line needs to be uncommented to support the dynamic syntax that I'm looking for.  Not sure why this isn't enabled by default.

From the source code:

```
// NOTE: uncomment the following line to enable dynamic support.
//#define SIMPLE_JSON_DYNAMIC
```

Comment: That's a fair comment, L.B.  I can't delete the question, so hopefully this will serve as a useful artifact for others who install SimpleJson through NuGet and run into the same problem as I did.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the samples, `JsonObject` properties are accessed like a dictionary. So instead of `json.foo`, you would need `json["foo"]`.

You are actually worse off using `dynamic` here, since there's nothing dynamic about it: the method returns `JsonObject`, which simply doesn't have a `foo` member. If you hadn't used `dynamic`, you could have gotten that error message at compile time.

If you have a look at the link L.B. provided, it shows how to implement this dynamic functionality yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**>csc /t:library /d:SIMPLE_JSON_DYNAMIC SimpleJson.cs**